# Moving an element up/down a sortable list while keeping the element in same position in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items. The format is something like this:

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|        SPACER DIV          |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|        ELEMENT DIV         |
|                            |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|        SPACER DIV          |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|        ELEMENT DIV         |
|                            |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I am using a jQuery script to move a element up/down the list:

```
$(sortableContainer).on('click', '.sortable-controls i', function(e){
            var that = $(e.target);
            var item = that.closest(panel);
            var thisWindow = $(window);
            var scrollTop           = thisWindow.scrollTop(),
                elementOffsetTop    = item.offset().top,
                distanceTop         = (elementOffsetTop - scrollTop);

            if(that.hasClass('sortable-up')) {

                var filler = item.prev();
                var prev = item.prevAll(panel).first();
                if (prev.length == 0)
                    return;
                item.prev().remove();

                prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position','relative').animate({
                    top: item.height() 
                }, 250);
                item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: '-' + prev.height(), queue: false}, 300, function () {
                    prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
                    item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
                    item.insertBefore(prev);
                    filler.insertBefore(prev);
                    Abayo.builder.updateSorted(item, sortableContainer);
                });
                var scrollDifference = distanceTop - prev.height() - filler.height();

                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollDifference, queue: false }, 300);

            } else if(that.hasClass('sortable-down')) {

                var filler = item.next();
                var next = item.nextAll(panel).first();
                if (next.length == 0)
                    return;
                item.next().remove();

                next.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({ 
                    top: '-' + item.height() 
                }, 250);
                item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({ top: next.height(), queue: false }, 300, function () {
                    next.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
                    item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
                    item.insertAfter(next);
                    filler.insertAfter(next);
                    Abayo.builder.updateSorted(item, sortableContainer);
                });

                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: distanceTop + next.height() + filler.height(), queue: false }, 300);

            }
        })
```

Sadly this doesn't work well when the element is not exactly in the middle and there are enough elements to create a overflow-y.

How to change this script in that it always keep the element in viewport and also consider the viewport size?

I must be able to click a top element all the way down, but after a few clicks the down-button falls outside my viewport, and I have to manually scroll to continue this.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/6wvuf1kc/7/)

Comment: Hard to visualize issue in demo when all the elements have same content and style

Comment: Seriously? Move the element down some times, you see that it fails to stay within viewport..

Comment: At least provide some difference so we don't have to play with it to try to figure it out. When I move something that says "Some Content" that's exactly what I see each time

Comment: Sigh, https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/6wvuf1kc/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what I did wrong.
I first needed to calculate what the current offsetTop of the viewport was.

```
var scroll  =   thisWindow.scrollTop(),
                elementOffset   = item.offset().top,
                distance        = (elementOffset - scroll);
```

The `distance` calculated is just the distance from the element to the viewport.
To get the current offset I just had to substract the calculated `distance` from the `item.offset().top`. Then I just needed to substract/add the prev/next item height:

Element up:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  elementOffset - distance - prev.height(), queue: false }, 300);
```

Element down:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  elementOffset - distance + next.height(), queue: false }, 300);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/6wvuf1kc/12/)

Answer (score 1):

If I use the element's offset it seems to stop the element from leaving the viewport:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: prev.offset().top - 50, queue: false }, 300);

$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top, queue: false }, 300);
```

Comment: I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/6wvuf1kc/11/, but the element still moves up/down in the viewport, I want to maintain the viewport position also.